# Are there any limits to how many app services a single app insights service can handle?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-app-service-plans, appinsights

Id like to understand if there is any limit to the number of app services that can have a direct dependency on a single instance of an app insights service.

Right now I am exploring creating a dedicated appinsight service instance for many apps.

Are there any limitations that I need to be aware of?
At what point am I going to run into issues? How many apps? 100? 1000?

Comment: Doesn’t look like there is a limit on concurrent Apps, just on the amount of data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/service-limits#application-insights

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not suggested ([Daniel Stocker's blog](https://www.danielstocker.net/application-insights-one-or-many-ai-resources-per-app/)), there is no limit to use one Application Insight for multiple Apps. Some other limitations:

- The maximum daily cap is 1,000 GB/day unless you request a higher maximum for a high-traffic application.
- Throttling limits the data rate to 32,000 events per second, averaged over 1 minute per instrumentation key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing